# Looping over json data from your database in twig

Tags: php, doctrine, twig, symfony

So currently l have got in my controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ApiBundle:Request');

    $themes = $repository->findAll();

    return $this->render('ApiBundle:Default:index.html.twig', ['themes' => $themes]);
}
```

and in my twig:

```
{% for theme in themes %}
    <div am-col="md-6">
        <div am-row>
            <div am-col="md-3">
               {{ theme.preview|json_encode }}
            </div>
            <div am-col="md-8">
                {{ theme.name }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now the `theme.previews` returns a json as below:

```
{"icon_with_video_preview":{"icon_url":"https:\/\/0.s3.envato.com\/files\/170231072\/design-wordpress80.png","landscape_url":"https:\/\/0.s3.envato.com\/files\/170231083\/design-wordpresspreview.jpg","video_url":"https:\/\/0.s3.envato.com\/h264-video-previews\/02e0816d-0957-45c4-af2c-792e37bcc37a\/14727479.mp4"}}
```

l need to access and display the icon_url. Any ideas? l currently tried `{{ theme.preview.icon_with_video_preview.icon_url }}` but get an error saying this array cannot be converted to string.

Comment: You might want to post the exact code you used, the exact error and relevant parts of your entity/entities.

Answer (score 1):

I think for this case you might need to send a json encoded variable from controller like so:

```
return $this->render('ApiBundle:Default:index.html.twig',[
    'themes' => $themes,
    'json_themes' => json_encode($themes),
]);
```

Then in your Twig you can call like you need:

```
{% for jtheme in json_themes %}
    {{ jtheme.preview.icon_with_video_preview.icon_url }}
{% endfor %}
```

I included both in the controller in case you need to use both json and non-json variables. Adjust as needed.

Let us know if that works, I think it should, but you might need something different.

Comment: Hi there Kelvin. Did this work? If it did, can you mark this as the correct answer by clicking on the checkmark. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dumping different things along the way to see if it returns the same error?

```
 {{ dump(theme.preview) }}
 {{ dump(theme.preview.icon_with_video_preview) }}
 {{ dump(theme.preview.icon_with_video_preview.icon_url) }}
```

Ultimately, you may need to access the array key using twig's `attribute` function. i.e.:

```
 {{ attribute(theme.preview, 'icon_with_video_preview').icon_url }}
```

See: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html